# Hosted Chef - slow Cookbook synchronization

Tags: chef-infra

Running `chef-client` causes chef to synchronize cookbooks. The only problem here is that `chef-client` **synchronizes each cookbook file by file, which takes about 3 seconds per file** so the whole process is very slow.

Is this expected behavior ? Is there anything I can do to make it faster ?

***Note:***
I think my question is connected to this issue: https://tickets.opscode.com/browse/CHEF-4423

Comment: Did any of the answers work for you?  =Please don't forget to mark an answer as correct! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is expected behavior. Checksums are verified and local cache is compared with the remote. The speed of this process is entirely dependent on your network connection.

Answer (score -1):

chef-client will attempt to establish a connection with chef server using the organization and user pem validations. 
so far, hosted chef provides good speed for operations. You have to check out with your network connections. Also, please make a note that :- chef server with make synchronization, Converging and Compilation of the cookbook. It depends on the number of cookbook you have provided in the chef server for execution.